# Which Webpack loader to HTML SPA pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am refactoring an old Angluar/NodeJS fullstack project. I am moving it from NodeJS v8 to NodeJS v14. This project is very big and very complex.

After a lot of work on removing/adding/updating npm packages and code renewal, now I am stuck in in the following Webpack issue:

```
ERROR in ./client/app/stats/authRequest/authRequest.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <div class="container bs-docs-container users-container" >
| 
|   <div class="row">
 @ ./client/app/stats/authRequest/authRequest.routes.js 8:14-43
 @ ./client/app/stats/authRequest/index.js
 @ ./client/app/stats/index.js
 @ ./client/app/app.js
```

Which HTML file is:

```
<div class="container bs-docs-container users-container" >

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label>{{'SEARCH_USER' | translate}}</label>
      <div id="lines" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:2%">
        <label for="search_user"></label><input id="search_user" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.docFilter.user" ng-change="ctrl.getDocs(ctrl.docFilter)" placeholder="{{'SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

This is only one of the HTML files that are "affected" by this issue, for the sake of simplicity I posted only this one.

The "strange" thing I noticed I that these HTML files start with a `<div>...</div>` instead of the usual `<html>...</html>`. I am unsure it could be legal doing it. Uh..! This is a big SPA (single page application) project.

I have not updated yet the Webpack config for now (apart some configurations about prod/dev modes and some flags), so it is at least 99% remanis unchanged from the NodeJS v8 project. I suppose the logic about Angular loaders is the following piece of code:

> webpack.make.js

```
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig(options) {
    ...
    let config = {}
    ...
    if(TEST) {
        config.entry = {};
    } else {
        config.entry = {
            app: './client/app/app.js',
            polyfills: './client/polyfills.js',
            vendor: [
                'angular',
                'angular-animate',
                'angular-aria',
                'angular-cookies',
                'angular-resource',
                'angular-socket-io',
                'angular-sanitize',
                'angular-ui-bootstrap',
                'angular-ui-router',
                'lodash'
            ]
        };
    }
    ...
    return config
}
```

But I am not sure, since I never used Webpack before and I am still learning on how to use it.

Any idea about this issue? How I could solve it?

I have yet to frame the issue and figure out exactly what the cause is, but I hope the described infos could be sufficient for you.

Comment: How are you importing the HTML file? Do you have a webpack loader that handles HTML?

Comment: I solved by adding following Webpack rule:

` {
        // This plugin will allow us to use html templates when we get to the angularJS app
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      }`